# List formatting issues

Tags: html, structure

Any ventures on why this list will show in all browsers except Fx 3.5 + ?
It worked fine until an update of the member base, effectively doubling the list.
Fx cuts it off @ 194 users, about half of the old list, which previously displayed with no problems.

PS. User 194's name is lost as well. I have chopped this into pieces, leaving only 10 extra users, same result- no joy.

[Ordered List](http://www.tsptalk.com/tracker/tsp_user_balance_all_full.php)

**Update:** The link no longer demonstrates the original problem. The original page included a large set of nested tables, which *were missing proper closing tags*.

Comment: 1999 called, and they want their HTML back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered `</center>` tags?

Comment: I also recommend adding the end tags, and see if that solves the problem. You create more then 200 levels of nested tags in the first 194 lines. Maybe FF bites the dust on that.

Comment: @Craig: please comment here rather than posting elsewhere on the page -- stackoverflow distinguishes between 'comments' and 'answers'. Regarding the HTML: consider using the W3C HTML validator. For example, http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=www.stackoverflow.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 validates immediately. Your page seems to cause the validator to take A Very Long Time, which suggests that your HTML has some serious structural issues. I recommend picking a small sample of your page, running it through the validator, and fixing whatever it finds.

Comment: & inti
Right you both were. Closing the tags brought things back in order, and thank you for the validator link. If I had reps to give, I'd pass them along.

Comment: @Craig You don't have to have rep to give rep. Upvote this answer, and when enough time has elapsed, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it.